# How to concatenate along a dimension of a single pytorch tensor?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor

I wrote a custom pytorch `Dataset` and the `__getitem__()` function return a tensor with shape `(250, 150)`, then I used `DataLoader` to generate a batch of data with batch size 10. My intension was to have a batch with shape `(2500, 150)` as concatenation of these 10 tensors along dimension 0, but the output of `DataLoader` has shape `(10, 250, 150)`. How do I transform the output of `DataLoader` into shape `(2500, 150)` as concatenation along dimension 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyTorch DataLoader will always add an extra batch dimension at 0th index. So, if you get a tensor of shape `(10, 250, 150)`, you can simple reshape it with

```
# x is of shape (10, 250, 150)
x_ = x.view(-1, 150)
# x_ is of shape (2500, 150)
```

Or, to be more correct, you can supply a custom *collator* to your dataloader

```
def custom_collate(batch):
    # each item in batch is (250, 150) as returned by __getitem__
    return torch.cat(batch, 0)

dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10, collate_fn=custom_collate, ...)
```

This will create properly sized tensor right in the dataloder itself, so no need for any post-processing with `.view()`.

Comment: I approve the solution with `collate_fn` (was about to post it myself ;-) ), since the behavior is then separated from any "free-standing logic". Further, `.view()` is known to only generate a *view* of the tensor, but not actually a new (and contiguous) representation in memory.